# Is it possible to MQPUT using MQCCSI_EMBEDDED?

Tags: xml, character-encoding, ibm-mq, codepages

I'm looking for a clean way of posting an XML message over a queue. Currently we have to inspect the XML `encoding` declaration and make sure to set the `MQMD.ccsid` accordingly (utf-8 = 1208). We also set the `MQMD.format` to `MQFMT_NONE`.

This appears to be fine, however some consumers are doing MQGET with `MQGMO_CONVERT` and that destroys the UTF-8 encoding.

They should **not** be calling the convert option when consuming non-text messages. But they are dealing with mixed text+non-text on the same queue.

I would like to use the special CCSID `MQCCSI_EMBEDDED` which states that the encoding information is found inside the message, exactly what XML does.

Unfortunately, setting the CCSID on MQPUT to that value defaults to the QMGR's ccsid.

See: [CCSID documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097460_.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you set the MD.Format to MQFMT_NONE when your application puts a message to a queue then the "get with convert" by the receiving application does NOT perform a convert.

Either you set MD.Format to MQFMT_STRING or the receiving application messed up.

Also, you do know that if you read a message into a String buffer in Java that the JVM will convert it to the encoding that the JVM is running under.